# ArcGIS like stretched color scheme in R for Rasters

Tags: r, plot, arcgis, raster

I'm trying to replicate the stretched color scheme employed by ArcGIS for displaying rasters in R.  I want to use the method that defines the min/max of the color scale as mean(raster_values) +/- 2*sd(raster_values), and then anything outside this range will get set to the colors of the min or max depending upon the inequality.

I don't know how to tell R to plot all the values above/below the threshold as the max/min color value (it just doesn't color the cells).

```
#Load libraries
  library(raster)
  library(RColorBrewer)

#Color scale
  bluescale = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"PuBu"))

#Create raster and plot it 
  x = raster(matrix(rnorm(625,20,5),25,25))
  plot(x,col=bluescale(50),breaks=seq(mean(values(x))-2*sd(values(x)),mean(values(x))+2*sd(values(x)),length.out=51))
```

[image]

It doesn't plot all the values.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just extending the breaks for those last groups

```
br <- seq(mean(values(x))-2*sd(values(x)),
    mean(values(x))+2*sd(values(x)),length.out=51)
br[1] <- min(values(x));
br[length(br)] <- max(values(x))
plot(x,col=bluescale(50),breaks=br)
```

[image]